# Making a simple password checker in HTML/Javascript that displays a div upon correct password

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make code for a simple password checker that will be part of a website I give to students for an activity. I don't care if the password is easy to find in the code. I just want the students to be able enter a password, and press enter or click the button to see if the password is correct.

This is the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function isValid(){
  var keyvalue = document.getElementById('keyvalue').value;
  if (keyvalue == "miranda")
    {document.getElementById('welcomeDiv').style.display = "block";}
  else
    {alert('ACCESS DENIED')}
  }
</script>
```

The HTML

```
<form name="PasswordField" action="">
  Type Password Below:</br>
  <input type="text" id="keyvalue" name="keyvalue" onkeydown = "if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('subPass).click()">
  <input type="button" id="subPass" value="ACCESS" onclick="isValid(this);">
</form>

<div id="welcomeDiv" style="display:none;" class="answer_list">
  </br>
  <p>ACCESS GRANTED</p></br>
  <a href="google.com">Click to go to next stage.</a>
</div>
```

Clicking the button works well, but if I press enter it will flash the hidden div briefly before reloading the page, thus hiding the div again. I'm trying to figure out how to prevent it from doing this.

Comment: `getElementById('subPass)` - is the `'` missing in your actual code as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `action=""` is probabaly not doing what you what it to.
Use `onsubmit="return false;"' instead:

```
<form name="PasswordField" onsubmit="return false;">
  Type Password Below:</br>
  <input type="text" id="keyvalue" name="keyvalue" onkeydown = "if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('subPass').click()">
  <input type="button" id="subPass" value="ACCESS" onclick="isValid(this);">
</form>
```

Or just make it a `<div` instead of a `<form`

Answer (score 0):

The button is submitting the form, reloading the page.

In the `onclick` attribute of your button you need to `return false` to override the browser's default behaviour of actually sending the form:

```
<input type="button" id="subPass" value="ACCESS" onclick="isValid(this); return false">
```

As Marvin mentioned in a comment you also need to fix the quotes in the `onkeydown` attribute of your text input and remove some extra spaces:

```
<input type="text" id="keyvalue" name="keyvalue" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('subPass').click()">
```